# 3d Studio Max texture doesnt show in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

i am using Unity latest version and 3ds Max 2014. When i export my 3d model to .fbx format it shows me the following message:

> "The following maps are only supported by 3ds Max; they will not be recognized by other applications. To learn how to convert them so they will be compatible with other applications, see the Render Map Dialog topic in the 3ds Max documentation...."

Also when i import my .fbx file in Unity, the same maps are not shown at all (as expected). These maps are bitmaps taken from .png files

Any hints on how to make these maps recognized by Unity ?

Comment: Export as UV/Normal/Specular/etc maps and use them in Unity?

Comment: I am going to try and re-assign them in the compact material editor and see what happens....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It should be posted on:
 http://gamedev.stackexchange.com (or Unity Answers)